# Increase resolution of ListContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have this code that I want to compute to create at Gyroid,

```
ListContourPlot3D[
Table[Cos[4 z] Sin[4 x] + Cos[4 x] Sin[4 y] + Cos[4 y] Sin[4 z], 
    {x, 0, 35}, 
    {y, 0, 35}, 
    {z, 0, 60}], 
Contours -> 0, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

However, the `PerformanceGoal` is set to `Quality` but I don't get an adequate quality.  I would like to increase it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to increase the [`MaxPlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html),

Here is the default option,

```
dta = Table[
   Cos[4*z] Sin[4*x] + Cos[4*x] Sin[4*y] + Cos[4*y] Sin[4*z], {x, 0, 
    35}, {y, 0, 35}, {z, 0, 60}];
ListContourPlot3D[dta, Contours -> 0]
```

[image]

And here it is setting `MaxPlotPoints` to a high value,

```
ListContourPlot3D[dta, Contours -> 0, MaxPlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Setting this value too high will seriously slow down your system though, so be warned.

### Edit

There are two points to consider here, first the number of points in your data, and secondly the number of points that the plotting function uses.

In your example, you only take points at whole numbers: at `x = 1, 2, 3, 4` etc.  Your resolution will be limited by this.  You can increase this resolution as shown below.  Next you can increase the `MaxPlotPoints` as well.

Finally, I think you should generate the `Table` beforehand so that you don't have to regenerate it every time you want to change your plot.

```
With[{ω = (1 + .2 z)},
 dta = Table[
    Cos[ω x] Sin[ω y] + 
     Cos[ω y] Sin[ω z] + 
     Cos[ω z] Sin[ω x], {x, -0, 16, .25}, {y, -0, 
     16, .25}, {z, -0, 16, .25}];
 ]

ListContourPlot3D[dta, Contours -> {0}, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
 Extrusion -> .2, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Another neat thing to try is to change the shape of the resulting plot, using `RegionFunction`

```
ListContourPlot3D[dta, Contours -> {0}, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
 Extrusion -> .2, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 DataRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 36]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: is there any other way to do it? I´m doing it to create file that be exported in STL format.  is there a smart way to export this?

Comment: Does it have to be a list plot, or can you plot the function?  Is this the exact plot you want to make, or are you trying for a more complicated plot?

Comment: i can plot the function directly if that speeds up as long as i have resolution and the possiblity to add Extrusion part to thicken the walls for 3d printing

Comment: Actually i dont need to do the plotting can i simply export the function to  a stl format?

Comment: @pblomstrom - you either need to create a 3D region or a Graphics3D object in order to create an STL file (see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html)).  I just created an STL file from the tennis-ball looking object above, and I opened it in MeshLab and it looks just as would be expected, and it did not take very long, especially compared to how long it would take to print it I think.

Comment: was just asking because that would be even better. No the time need to print is much much more. so really appreciate your help